# Computing "approximate" absorbed power for an AC motor of a pump from missing data

Tags: power, motor, ac

I have an year's worth of time series data for a pump: a lot of data are missing. I would like to estimate the trend of the absorbed power with time. I don't need to get an accurate estimate of power: I just need to have an idea of the power trend during the year.

I forgot how to estimate absorbed power for an AC motor. For a direct current system, clearly electric power absorbed by a system with one input and one output is equal to the product of the voltage differential between input and output, times current at input or output (they are equal). In my case (AC current) I have the following sensors measurements, at regular intervals in time:

- `Amps_out_A, Amps_out_B, Amps_out_C, Volts_out_AB, Volts_out_BC, Volts_out_CA, Amps_in_A, Amps_in_B, Amps_in_C, Volts_in_AB, Volts_in_BC, Volts_in_CA`

I think these are currents in input & output at the three phases (A, B, C), and voltage differentials across the phases (AB, BC, CA), again for input and output. The problem is that many of these data are missing. Precisely, *all* measurements for `Amps_in_A, Amps_in_B, Amps_in_C, Volts_out_BC, Volts_out_CA` are missing. Is it still possible to estimate the absorbed power with the other measurements, and if so, how?

The sensor measurements file contains also other sensor measurements. The names of all the variables for which at least one measurement is available are:

```
DataKey
WellID
TimeGMT
Freq
FreqSP
Pip
Pdp
Ptbg
Tin
MTemp
Xvib
Yvib
Amps_out_A
Amps_out_B
Amps_out_C
Volts_out_AB
Volts_in_AB
Volts_in_BC
Volts_in_CA
LastSD
DataSource
XRatio
```

Comment: A three-phase motor has only three input currents and three input voltages. The outputs are torque, speed and power. Does some of the sensor data apply to a motor speed controller or something like that? Revise the question to list all of the information on the motor rating plate. List all of the data on the speed controller if there is one.

Comment: @CharlesCowie thanks for the information. Currently, the answer to your questions is "I have no idea" (I also have no access to the motor rating plate). Next week I'll try to get in touch with people who may know the answers and let you know. Would it help if I added the names of all measured quantities? Keep in mind that currently I don't know what most of those names mean.

Comment: The names of the measured quantities would help.

Comment: @CharlesCowie there you go.

Comment: The brand and model of the device supplying the measurement file might help. You could search for explanations of the quantities. However the people you get in touch with next week may be the best source.